# What are possible golang http response errors?

Tags: http, go

As in many golang `net/http` articles, a request returns two values: response and error:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
```

For http-related errors, it will be returned in `resp` with status code like 502, 400 etc. What are the possible errors returned? I need to know them before I can handle them.

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#pkg-constants

Comment: @Marty I did not mean status code error, because they are returned in `resp`, I want to know that is returned as `err` in the first line of above code.

Comment: I was looking for this same question bur instead got an question which had 5 down votes and closed. Thanks @cizixs for asking this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. URL parse error
2. too much redirect times
3. tcp connect\write\read timeout
4. 302 status, but null Location header

and so on

You can read the source code in http package. Then you can find all the errors returned by this function `http.Get`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, This really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Those errors will mostly network related errors, like network timeouts etc. There is no need to handle them differently. You may exit gracefully like,

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://google.com/")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

there are many error responses like :-

```
301 (Moved Permanently)
302 (Found)
303 (See Other)
307 (Temporary Redirect)
```

better you go and read [http.Get](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_Get)